With ZFS snapshot rollback the file system remains unchanged
Server with latest version available and ZFS File System.
I tried ZFS Snapshot. Below is the list of commands.
First I check if the zpool is available and create the snapshot.
At this point I copy a dozen emails and folders.
Then a rollback command I go back to email. If the rollback had worked the emails should have disappeared, instead the mail is still there.
Or am I wrong?
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
zp0    444G  8.86G   435G        -         -     0%     1%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot
no datasets available
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs snapshot zp0@Testss
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot
NAME         USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zp0@Testss     0B      -       96K  -
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot
NAME         USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zp0@Testss     0B      -       96K  -

#### Send emails

admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs rollback zp0@Testss

### Verified presence of emails

admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot
NAME         USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
zp0@Testss     0B      -       96K  -
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs destroy zp0@Testss
admin@srv1:~$ sudo zfs list -t snapshot
no datasets available


Instead of try&error, I recommend reading the documentation of your operating system and ZFS. Just a hint,  the mail folder is often exempted in snapshot rollbacks, as log folders and home folders and several others.
